# Convert "11:00 to 12:00" TO "11:00 am to 12:00 pm"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, datetime, time

I want to convert given date string:
"11:00 to 12:00"

to

"11:00 am to 12:00 pm".

I have tried several methods which convert ISODateString. But I am unable to work out this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to only change format like this:- `DateFormat("h:mm a");`
It is returns 11:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

use this package https://pub.dev/packages/intl

use it like below,

```
var format = DateFormat("h:mm a");
var dateString = format.format(DateTime.now());
```